# Where are currently set wallpapers stored in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

I have set a wallpaper to my desktop, now I want to consolidate all my wallpapers into a single folder so the system can cycle through them.

How can I find a currently set wallpaper's location?

Comment: How have you set it? System wallpapers are in `/Library/Desktop Pictures`.

Comment: One thing to note in the links and the above answer (which is good) is that you don't want to do CMD+Shift+G and then select enter ~/Library/Desktop Pictures - as this will take to you the Library folder under your User in the mac. You want to go to a different library - directly off of your hard drive at the root level - that's where this is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this hint: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/20/show-the-location-path-of-current-wallpaper-in-mac-os-x/

You can (temporarily) show the location of the current desktop picture by executing the following command from the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock
```

You can revert this behavior by executing the following:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text;killall Dock
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint. I was looking for this since I just found the addtional Wallpapers ment for Retina display in the System somewhere and wanted to copy them over to the regular folder for the backgr pics. Thanks again
Manfredo/Hamburg(Germany)

Comment: Unfortunately, that reset my wallpaper to another random one in the collection, defeating the purpose :( Although it did show the location of the new wallpaper ;)